# WatcherAdapter's first argument must be an array of SourceNodeWrapper nodes

Tags: ember.js

While configuring Ember project on my local PC. 
I have installed all the required packages. But when I try to build the project it gave me error.

After some research I found a solution, to uninstall ember-browserify and use ember-auto-import instead.
I tried to uninstall the ember-browserify. It helps to create a successful build but ember-pusher requires the ember-browserify and my app doesn't load properly.

Then I go back on installing the ember-browserify and have no luck till yet to fix the issue.

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "compliance",
  "version": "2.36.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Ember application for COMpliance API",
  "repository": "",
  "license": "",
  "author": "",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "lint:hbs": "ember-template-lint .",
    "lint:js": "eslint .",
    "start": "ember serve",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ember/jquery": "^0.5.2",
    "@ember/optional-features": "^0.6.4",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.676.0",
    "ember-ajax": "^3.1.0",
    "ember-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^3.2.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^6.18.0",
    "ember-cli-chart": "^3.6.0",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^3.2.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy": "^1.0.2",
    "ember-cli-deploy-build": "^1.1.2",
    "ember-cli-deploy-cloudfront": "~1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-display-revisions": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-deploy-gzip": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-deploy-manifest": "~1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-revision-data": "~1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-s3": "~1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-deploy-s3-index": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-deploy-slack": "^1.0.1",
    "ember-cli-dotenv": "1.2.0",
    "ember-cli-dropzonejs": "^1.3.6",
    "ember-cli-eslint": "^4.2.3",
    "ember-cli-flash": "^1.8.1",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^3.1.0",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^1.0.3",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.8.2",
    "ember-cli-lightbox": "1.0.2",
    "ember-cli-mentionable": "0.0.10",
    "ember-cli-moment-shim": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^4.3.2",
    "ember-cli-sass": "^7.2.0",
    "ember-cli-sentry": "^2.4.4",
    "ember-cli-shims": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.1",
    "ember-cli-string-helpers": "^1.10.0",
    "ember-cli-template-lint": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-windows-addon": "^1.3.1",
    "ember-data": "^3.18.0",
    "ember-drag-drop": "^0.5.1",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^2.0.1",
    "ember-highcharts": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-infinity": "^1.4.9",
    "ember-initials": "^3.13.0",
    "ember-jquery-legacy": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^1.1.0",
    "ember-maybe-import-regenerator": "^0.1.6",
    "ember-moment": "6.1.0",
    "ember-radio-button": "1.2.0",
    "ember-resolver": "^5.3.0",
    "ember-responsive-tabs": "^1.0.7",
    "ember-side-menu": "^0.1.0",
    "ember-simple-auth": "^1.9.2",
    "ember-source": "^3.18.1",
    "ember-tag-input": "^1.2.2",
    "ember-toggle": "^5.3.3",
    "ember-tooltips": "^3.4.2",
    "ember-welcome-page": "^3.2.0",
    "ember-wormhole": "^0.5.5",
    "eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "^4.17.47",
    "eslint-plugin-ember": "^5.4.0",
    "highcharts": "^6.2.0",
    "loader.js": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.25.3",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.2",
    "pdfjs-dist": "^2.3.200",
    "pusher-js": "^3.1.0",
    "qunit-dom": "^0.8.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.* || 8.* || >= 10.*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^3.0.0",
    "ember-browserify": "^1.2.2",
    "ember-cli": "^3.18.0",
    "ember-progress-bar": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-pusher": "^1.1.1",
    "jam-icons": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery-csv": "^1.0.11",
    "liquid-fire": "^0.31.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1"
  }
}
```

Error log:

```
=================================================================================

ENV Summary:

  TIME: Fri May 15 2020 18:37:52 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
  TITLE: ember
  ARGV:
  - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
  - C:\Users\upervaiz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli\bin\ember
  - s
  EXEC_PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
  TMPDIR: C:\Users\upervaiz\AppData\Local\Temp
  SHELL: null
  PATH:
  - C
  - \ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C
  - \Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C
  - \Python37\Scripts\;C
  - \Python37\;C
  - \Program Files\Python37\Scripts\;C
  - \Program Files\Python37\;C
  - \Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C
  - \Windows\system32;C
  - \Windows;C
  - \Windows\System32\Wbem;C
  - \Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C
  - \Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C
  - \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C
  - \Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C
  - \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C
  - \Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C
  - \Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C
  - \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C
  - \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C
  - \Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C
  - \Python27\;C
  - \Python27\Scripts;C
  - \Program Files\PuTTY\;C
  - \Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin;C
  - \Program Files\Git;"C
  - \Windows;C
  - \Windows\System32;C
  - \Python27";C
  - \Program Files\helm\windows-amd64;C
  - \Program Files\IBM\Cloud\bin;C
  - \xampp\php;C
  - \ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C
  - \WINDOWS\system32;C
  - \WINDOWS;C
  - \WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C
  - \WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C
  - \WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C
  - \Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin;C
  - \AIRSDK\bin;C
  - \Program Files (x86)\gnupg\bin;C
  - \Program Files\nodejs\;C
  - \Program Files\Git\cmd;C
  - \Program Files\Git\bin;C
  - \Users\upervaiz\AppData\Roaming\npm;C
  - \Users\upervaiz\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C
  - \Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre\bin\server;C
  - \Users\upervaiz\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C
  - \Program Files (x86)\Nmap;C
  - \Users\upervaiz\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C
  - \Users\upervaiz\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C
  - \Users\upervaiz\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C
  - \Users\upervaiz\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C
  - \Users\upervaiz\AppData\Roaming\npm
  PLATFORM: win32 x64
  FREEMEM: 3896344576
  TOTALMEM: 17054658560
  UPTIME: 12891
  LOADAVG: 0,0,0
  CPUS:
  - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz - 2496
  - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz - 2496
  - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz - 2496
  - Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz - 2496
  ENDIANNESS: LE
  VERSIONS:
  - ares: 1.16.0
  - brotli: 1.0.7
  - cldr: 36.0
  - http_parser: 2.9.3
  - icu: 65.1
  - llhttp: 2.0.4
  - modules: 72
  - napi: 5
  - nghttp2: 1.40.0
  - node: 12.16.3
  - openssl: 1.1.1g
  - tz: 2019c
  - unicode: 12.1
  - uv: 1.34.2
  - v8: 7.8.279.23-node.35
  - zlib: 1.2.11

ERROR Summary:

  - broccoliBuilderErrorStack: [undefined]
  - code: [undefined]
  - codeFrame: [undefined]
  - errorMessage: WatcherAdapter's first argument must be an array of SourceNodeWrapper nodes
  - errorType: [undefined]
  - location:
    - column: [undefined]
    - file: [undefined]
    - line: [undefined]
  - message: WatcherAdapter's first argument must be an array of SourceNodeWrapper nodes
  - name: TypeError
  - nodeAnnotation: [undefined]
  - nodeName: [undefined]
  - originalErrorMessage: [undefined]
  - stack: TypeError: WatcherAdapter's first argument must be an array of SourceNodeWrapper nodes
    at new WatcherAdapter (D:\Projects\Neb\Front\compliance-app\node_modules\broccoli\dist\watcher_adapter.js:18:19)
    at new Watcher (D:\Projects\Neb\Front\compliance-app\node_modules\broccoli\dist\watcher.js:23:44)
    at Watcher.constructBroccoliWatcher (D:\Projects\Neb\Front\compliance-app\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\watcher.js:45:19)
    at new Watcher (D:\Projects\Neb\Front\compliance-app\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\watcher.js:27:41)
    at ServeTask.run (D:\Projects\Neb\Front\compliance-app\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\tasks\serve.js:58:7)
    at D:\Projects\Neb\Front\compliance-app\node_modules\ember-cli\lib\models\command.js:238:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Comment: `ember-pusher` seems pretty outdated and unmaintained. I would strongly recommend you to not use it. Probably this will bring you back to the happy path.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```
"ember-pusher": "^1.1.1",
```

to

```
"ember-pusher": "truecoach/ember-pusher#2.0.1"
```

and remove `ember-browserify` and `pusher-js` from your `package.json`.

This will update ember-pusher to a fork on github not published to npm that uses ember-auto-import and does not require ember-browserify.